# How do I create multiple lines in my string for my Blog site?

Tags: python, django, string, django-models

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Title: {self.title}\nBlog: {self.text}"
```

I introduced the f-string format and attempted to utilize the "\n" method but the output is still on           same line when I run my server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the **str** method to print the object directly to the console or output, it is possible that your console or output is not recognizing the "\n" method as a new line character. In that case, you can try using the os module to handle new line characters based on your operating system.

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
text = models.TextField()
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f"Title: {self.title}{os.linesep}Blog: {self.text}{os.linesep}"
```